# How can I set a special format in a column or leave the field blank

Tags: list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, validation, formula

I have a column that is called APC Standard. In this column I want to set the following format APCxxxx (APC + 4 numbers). I also want to have the possibility to leave the column blank.

I have already found the formula for the desired format.

```
=IF(AND(LEN([APC Standard])=7,LEFT([APC Standard],3)="APC",ISNUMBER(0+RIGHT([APC Standard],4))),TRUE,FALSE)
```

However, I cannot find a way to leave the column blank.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already found the formula for your desired format, you can use below to check if the column is blank or not:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([APC Standard]), TRUE, IF(AND(LEN([APC Standard]) = 7, LEFT([APC Standard], 3) = "APC", ISNUMBER(0 + RIGHT([APC Standard], 4))), TRUE, FALSE))
```

**Reference**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))
2. [IS functions - ISBLANK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/is-functions-586532cc-9888-4ca0-98b8-c874e4c8a087)